# Adding info to sleuth tracing messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, jfr

I have sleuth defined in my spring boot application. It prints messages as in below example.

- How can I add more info to be printed from DispatcherServlet?
- How can I create JFR (Java  flight recorder) event with tracing info?
- Where exactly in DispatcherServlet it creates this message - I'd like to update it via instrumentation

*2021-02-06 21:11:37.661 DEBUG [,250addg195246a3,250addg195246a3] 11260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question does not contain too many details, I'm assuming a bunch of things here:

> How can I add more info to be printed from DispatcherServlet?

I guess you are referring to the tracing-info part (`[,250addg195246a3,250addg195246a3]`). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851232/971735) to understand how tracing data is injected there, by overriding the `logging.pattern.level`, you will be able to inject custom things there.

> How can I create JFR (Java flight recorder) event with tracing info?

You can inject a `Tracer` and get the current span from it, you can inject the data held by the span.

> Where exactly in DispatcherServlet it creates this message - I'd like to update it via instrumentation

This depends on what version are you using, you should be able find it by reading/debugging [it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java).