# Java Spring Sleuth Zipkin - X-Span-Export not being displayed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Small question as I am not able to see **X-Span-Export** in my logs please.

I have an app, which is Java based, with Springboot 2.4.2, with Sleuth and Zipkin.

In my log4j2.xml, I configured such:

```
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p - [%10.10t] %-30.30c{1.} : [%X{X-B3-TraceId}, %X{X-B3-SpanId}, %X{X-Span-Export}] %m%n%ex
    </Property>
```

However, in my logs, I am only able to see:

```
2021-03-07 13:12:40.218  INFO [myservice,336a9463f46cf034,18bffe81e7500eae] 562 --- [or-http-epoll-4] ...
```

I was expecting to see a "true" or "false", like `[myservice,336a9463f46cf034,18bffe81e7500eae,true]` however, it is not here.

May I know what is the issue please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was removed in Sleuth 3.0, though it seems the docs were not updated, I'm going to update the docs soon.

To fix the rest with your logs, you can check the logging config [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/5fc49aa485a68664dcdea83eaa366cb1142bcb32/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging), the [log integration in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-log-integration) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851232/971735).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, very clear, (upvote). Just for me to avoid confusion, how can I be sure I am using Sleuth 3.0, reason why I don't see %X{X-Span-Export}, and not because I did something wrong please?

Comment: That depends on a few things (your build tool, how to add Sleuth, etc.):
You can add the Spring Cloud BOM to your project, 2020.x will ensure you are using Sleuth 3.x: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2020.0.1/pom 
You can check the docs about how to do it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-pom

You can also ask your build tool or IDE to tell you which version are you using, please check the docs of your build tool/IDE.