# SpanID and TraceID missing in Spring Boot logs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

For example, before including Spring Cloud Sleuth, people get something like this in their logs

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO [my-service-id,,] 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MySimpleComponentMakingARequest
```

with the 2 commas (which is where the traceID and spanID would show up) near the application name. But my logs initially looked like this

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MySimpleComponentMakingARequest
```

In order to get the application name on my logs, I wrote the following code in application.properties

```
logging.pattern.level= %5p [${spring.application.name}]
```

and now my logs look like this (if you observe, it does not have the 2 commas next to the application name)

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO [my-service-id] 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.MySimpleComponentMakingARequest
```

and even after including Sleuth, my logs look this way and the SpanID and TraceID aren't present. I am new to Spring Boot, please help me out by telling me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sleuth uses `logging.pattern.level` to inject these details. Since you overwrite it, the details that Sleuth would put in there are not there.

If you don't set the property you should see this without Sleuth:

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ...
```

And if you include Sleuth:

```
2016-02-11 17:12:45.404  INFO [my-service-id,,] 85184 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ...
```

If this is not the behavior you experience, check your classpath, and make sure Sleuth is there/not there and you are using the right version.

See this answer for what is going on in the background: [How spring cloud sleuth adds tracing information to logback log lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846859/how-spring-cloud-sleuth-adds-tracing-information-to-logback-log-lines/65851232#65851232)

Comment: see also for spring boot 3 https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide#log-pattern