# what should I do to add new tags in sleuth, such as client ip address, I want to add the client ip address in logs, of course, with traceId, spanId

Tags: java, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to finish a log system, which is to monitor a spring cloud application. The spring-cloud application consists of several microservices, using sleuth for distributed tracing. I have set the pattern of log, and now there are tags like 'traceId', 'spanId', 'parentId' in the log. Now , I would like to add a new tag named 'client_ip' into the log. How can I make it ? And how to pass the client_ip tag to downstream microservice. Currently, my plan is to get client ip in api-gateway  service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with Sleuth.
You can modify your log settings and add what you want. Sleuth modifies the level in the pattern (`logging.pattern.level`) and adds these details there.

You can check this answer to see how sleuth does this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851232/971735