# How to add principal name in logs using Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

By default Spring Cloud Sleuth log such info as: Application name, TraceId, SpanId, Export.

is there a way to configure the module to add in logs also the principal name?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with Sleuth.
You can modify your log settings and add what you want. Sleuth modifies the level in the pattern (`logging.pattern.level`) and adds these details there.

You can check this answer to see how sleuth does this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851232/971735